# Return javascript field to default value after onkeyup

Tags: javascript

I have two fields where the second field has a value and whatever value is entered in the first field is added to the second value.
Now when it is added and the number entered in the first field is deleted(erased with backspace) the value of the second field does not not return to it's original value. How do I go about this? Also I won't mind a better way to approach `onkeyup` in this situation

Html:

```
First: <input type="text" id="vala"  onkeyup="sum();" />
Second: <input type="text" id="valb"  value="12" />
```

JS:

```
function sum() {
var first = document.getElementById('vala').value;
var second = document.getElementById('valb').value;
var result = parseInt(first) + parseInt(second);
if (!isNaN(result)) {
   document.getElementById('valb').value = result;
            }
        }
```

Working fiddle representation:
http://jsfiddle.net/wcvqby2g/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for

```
function sum() {
    var first = document.getElementById('vala').value;
    var second = document.getElementById('valb').defaultValue;
    var result = (parseInt(first) || 0) + parseInt(second);
    document.getElementById('valb').value = result;
}
```

where the [`defaultValue` property of the input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement) accesses the original value of the input, i.e. the one specified in the `value` attribute.

([updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wcvqby2g/6/))

Comment: I like this answer, I didn't think about using `defaultValue`.  Nice, clean, and simple!

Comment: I like this answer. Very clean as @HowardRenollet said

Answer (score 2):

It was overwritten.

You can store original value like this:

```
First: <input type="text" id="vala"  onkeyup="sum();" />
Second: <input type="text" id="valb"  value="12" data-default-value="12" />
```

...and add this to your JS:

```
else {
    document.getElementById('valb').value = document.getElementById('valb').dataset.defaultValue;
}
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/andunai/wcvqby2g/5/

Notice that `data-default-value` becomes `dataset.defaultValue`

Comment: @HowardRenollet right, but zackify also suggested to put the value inside JS. That's a solution, too.

Answer (score 0):

this is working solution--

```
First: <input type="text" id="vala"  onkeyup="sum();" />
Second: <input type="text" id="valb"  value="12" />

<script>
var second1=document.getElementById('valb').value;
var first1=document.getElementById('vala').value;
function sum() {
var first = document.getElementById('vala').value;
var second = document.getElementById('valb').value;
var result = parseInt(first) + parseInt(second1);
if (!isNaN(result)) {
   document.getElementById('valb').value = result;
            }
            if(first == first1)
            {

            document.getElementById('valb').value= second1;
            }

        }
        </script>
```